# Android : Upon Force close clear password in login screen

Tags: android

I have the following scenario, please help me to find possible solution...

1. I am logging into my application.
2. Then I navigate to different screens of my application.
3. Application crash in One scenario that i could not handle..That is while uploading the Video of large size.
4. Then it will give me Force close POP UP and then redirects to LOGIN Screen. There i 
    need to clear my password for the security reason.....

Anyone can help me to clear password when application crashes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your your code in a try catch block.  If you catch an exception, then clear the password.

If you are experiencing  a non-intended exception, you should probably re-work your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably fix the force close.

Comment: In our app we are doing server side communication...So some time it may arise due to Http connection or some network issue... So what i need is that when it happens i want to navigate back to my login screen and then clear password...So Now Do u get my question ??/Can u help me to do this...Thanks

Comment: Fix the force close by using a try-catch around the error-prone code, and handle the exception. The solution really is to fix the force close. Once that Force Close dialog appears, you can't get control back from the OS so what you want isn't possible. Just do the right thing.